# VSIX Detect that a solution has been created

Tags: c#, visual-studio, vsix

While Microsoft makes it "reasonably easy" to determine when a solution has been opened or closed in a VSIX extension

```
  IVsSolution.GetSolutionInfo(
out pbstrSolutionDirectory, 
out pbstrSolutionFile, 
out pbstrUserOptsFile);
```

I am puzzling how exactly in a VSIX extension can I get information / event on when a new solution is ***created***.  Is such a thing possible?

I'm assuming there must be some way to do this, but as the Microsoft extension documentation is sparse, I cannot find it.

Comment: The doco is terrible.  The best thing you can do is browse the _[Managed Package Framework sourcecode](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/extensibility/internals/using-the-managed-package-framework-to-implement-a-project-type-csharp?view=vs-2017)_.  A great real-world example is the [IronPython Language Extension](https://archive.codeplex.com/?p=ironpythonstudio)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the [IVsSolutionEvents.OnAfterOpenSolution(Object, Int32)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.visualstudio.shell.interop.ivssolutionevents.onafteropensolution) method, whose second parameter, fNewSolution is what you want: true if the solution is being created. false if the solution was created previously or is being loaded.

You get IVsSolutionEvents with the [IVsSolution.AdviseSolutionEvents(IVsSolutionEvents, UInt32)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.visualstudio.shell.interop.ivssolution.advisesolutionevents) / [IVsSolution.UnadviseSolutionEvents(UInt32)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.visualstudio.shell.interop.ivssolution.unadvisesolutionevents) methods

I created a working VSIX sample some time ago [HOWTO: Get solution events from a Visual Studio package](https://www.mztools.com/articles/2014/MZ2014024.aspx)

Comment: Carlos, much appreciated, brother.  Your code looks perfect.  Cheers!